# Getting error "dispatch is not a function" when combining two files [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am creating a todo List application using reactJS. If I write two different logic in two separate files it works just fine but while combining those two files it gives an error.

**RenderRemaining.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store/store';
import RenderRemainingData from './RenderRemainingData';

const RenderRemaining = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Tasks: </h2>
            <hr />
            {props.list.map((detail) => {
                return <RenderRemainingData key={detail.id} {...detail} />
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        list: state.todoReducer
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RenderRemaining);
```

**RenderRemainingData.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import removeTodo from '../actions/removeTodo';

const RenderRemainingData = ({ dispatch, todo, id, description, isCompleted }) => {
    if (!isCompleted) {
        return (
            <div key={id}>
                <h4>{todo}
                    <span className="float-right">
                        <a href="#" title="Remove" onClick={() => {
                            dispatch(removeTodo({todo, description, id}));
                        }}><i className="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                    </span>
                </h4>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return false;
}

export default connect()(RenderRemainingData);
```

Now above code works just fine.

After combining above two files as one js file in RenderRemaining.js and deleting RenderRemainingData.js file.

**RenderRemaining.js file:** (after combining)

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store/store';
import removeTodo from '../actions/removeTodo';

const RenderRemainingData = ({ dispatch, todo, id, description, isCompleted }) => {
    if (!isCompleted) {
        return (
            <div key={id}>
                <h4>{todo}
                    <span className="float-right">
                        <a href="#" title="Remove" onClick={() => {
                            dispatch(removeTodo({todo, description, id}));
                        }}><i className="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                    </span>
                </h4>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return false;
}

const RenderRemaining = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Tasks: </h2>
            <hr />
            {props.list.map((detail) => {
                return <RenderRemainingData key={detail.id} {...detail} />
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        list: state.todoReducer
    };
}

connect()(RenderRemainingData);
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RenderRemaining);
```

Now when an event of onClick occurs it gives an error as `dispatch is not a function` in console.

I don't know why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you are rendering the `RenderRemainingData` component inside `RenderRemaining` you are not passing the `dispatch`, but in case of separate file, component will receive the dispatch from `connect`.

Possible Solutions:

**1-** Pass the dispatch in props to `RenderRemainingData` component:

```
return <RenderRemainingData key={detail.id} {...detail} dispatch={props.dispatch} />
```

And remove this line:

```
connect()(RenderRemainingData);
```

**2- Another possible solution is:**

Use a wrapper component and instead of rendering `RenderRemainingData` render that Wrapper component. Like this:

```
const WrapperRenderRemainingData = connect()(RenderRemainingData);

return <WrapperRenderRemainingData key={detail.id} {...detail} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `connect()(SomeRandomComponent)` means you are calling a function which will return you a value, a new Component that you can use.

So in the case of two separate files, first you create a new Component with `connect()(RenderRemainingData)`, then you export the return value.

These two are equivalent.

```
export default connect()(SomeRandomComponent)
```

and

```
const newComponent = connect()(SomeRandomComponent)
export default newComponent
```

Now, if we look at bottom of your file containing the combined code.

```
connect()(RenderRemainingData);
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RenderRemaining);
```

First expression, creates a newComponent by wrapping `connect` around `RenderRemainingData`. But since you didn't assign the return value to a new identifier or `RenderRemainingData`( you can't because latter is a `const` , by the way). Also, when you pass a `function` as a parameter, it is passed by value, so altering the parameter function inside the calling function will not affect its usage outside the calling `function`.

Easiest Solution for you will be the one mentioned below.

```
const RenderRemainingData = connect()(props => {

  ///Add the implementation here

 })
```

There you go, you have a connected component in the same file, with dispatch available.